# How to display a website in a iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, razor

I am trying to display a website in an iframe using Razor asp.net but I'm getting the following error: Refused to display 'https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=y359VYr9L4PlUeaLg5gG' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

This is the code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myButton').click(function () {
            $('#myFrame').attr('src', "http://www.google.com");
        });
    });
</script>
<iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
<button id="myButton">
    Refresh IFrame
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The page you are trying to show have set a header that prevents it from being showed in an iframe - there is no way to show this in an iframe.

Comment: It isn't absolutely necessary to display the website in an iframe...i want only to display it but not open another tab

Answer (score 1):

Try using the object tags.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<object classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="http://www.google.com">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> <-->
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.google.com" style="width:100%; height:100%">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
<!--> <![endif]-->
```

EDIT: Or you can generate it with jquery:

```
<script>$("#testLoad").load("http://www.google.com/");</script>
<div id="testLoad"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google custom search](http://www.google.com/custom).
It's working fine with me.
It sends `X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL` which allows you to embed this site in your IFRAME. See https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/websearch/how-do-iusing-google-search/pjHnvDST2D4 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I finished this by simply adding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: position,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title:"This is the place."
    });  

    var contentString = 'Hello <strong>World</strong>!';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```